# Why generator object is not return generator?

Tags: python-3.x

I have simple iteration object that use generator. But `__iter__()` method of `Obj()` can not get iterator from `Generator().__init__()`

Live demo is [here](https://ideone.com/vZ97GL).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Obj():
  def __init__(self, word):
    self.word = word

  def __iter__(self):
    return Generator(self.word)

class Generator():
  def __init__(self, word):
    for l in word:
      yield l

obj = Obj('qwe')
it = iter(obj)

print(it.__next__())
print(it.__next__())
print(it.__next__())
```

I expect console output to be `'qwe'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__` cannot return or yield a non-`None` value. With what you have, `Generator` is not a generator object, but `Obj` is. `Obj.__iter__` is the method that should be `yield`ing values, and you can probably get rid of the `Generator` class altogether, unless it is used for other things that you haven't shown in your posted snippet.

```
class Obj():
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
    def __iter__(self):
        for l in self.word:yield l

obj = Obj('qwe')

print(obj.__next__())
print(obj.__next__())
print(obj.__next__())
```